# Pytest - RuntimeError: Working outside of application context

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I'm trying to write tests for endpoints that rely on information being present in the DB at the time the test is run

So I try and get one of my "Apps"

```py
def get_apps_list():
    apps = App.query.limit(1)
    return apps


APPS = get_apps_list()
```

I then use @pytest.mark.parametrize to pass that "app" to the test and use the id to test the endpoint like so :

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('app', APPS)
@patch('flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.verify_jwt_in_request')
def test_get_app_by_id(session, mock_verify, client, app):
    response = client.get('/application/get_by_id/' + app.id)

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.content_type == "application/json"
    assert b'Success: App Fetched successfully' in response.data
```

But I then get the error:

```
_____________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_apps.py ______________________________________________________________________________________ 
tests\test_apps.py:13: in <module>
    APPS = get_apps_list()
tests\test_apps.py:9: in get_apps_list
    apps = App.query.limit(1)
venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py:23: in __get__
    cls, session=cls.__fsa__.session()  # type: ignore[arg-type]
venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py:221: in __call__
    sess = self.registry()
venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py:638: in __call__
    key = self.scopefunc()
venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\session.py:111: in _app_ctx_id
    return id(app_ctx._get_current_object())  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py:508: in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
E   RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

EDIT:

I have added a pytest fixture to bring the flask app into context:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def app_context():
    # create an application context
    with app.app_context():
        # yield the app object
        yield app
```

but still face the same error